# Efficient transfer to stdin of subprocess

Tags: python, linux, ipc

I am trying to make a data transfer more efficient in a linux program which has multiple clients and one server. At the beginning, the client spawns a subprocess and sends a big structure serialized using pickle (about 200MB). Then, depending on some events the clients send more data (not shown in this example code). The server then calls select (since there are multiple clients you can't just do a blocking read on one file descriptor), and then calls read() in order to read chunks of this pickle structure. Parsing those chunks takes about 0.01 seconds.

I noticed a strongly degraded performance due to the fact that those chunks are most of the time only 65536 bytes in size, and thus the parsing is done thousands of times. Ironically, if I load the CPU of the machine to 100% before starting this test, those chunks are a lot bigger, and the whole transfer is about 100 times faster. In this example code, if I comment-out the line `time.sleep(0.1)` in the test-server, the chunks are also about 622KB most of the time instead of 65536 bytes.

I tried to modify the values of "bufsize" in the client and "buffering" in the server in order to increase the size of those chunks, but it didn't change anything.

Here is some minimal code reproducing the issue:

Test client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
import subprocess
import time

input_data = random.randbytes(100_000_000)
worker = subprocess.Popen(["./server-test.py"], stdout=1, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=100_000)

start1 = time.time()
worker.stdin.write(input_data)
end1 = time.time()
print("stdin.write took %s" % (end1 - start1))
```

Test server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import fcntl
import os
import select
import sys
import time

class TestWorker(object):
    def __init__(self, din):
        self.input = din
        fcntl.fcntl(din, fcntl.F_SETFL, fcntl.fcntl(din, fcntl.F_GETFL) | os.O_NONBLOCK)
        self.build_pipes = {}
        self.queue = bytearray()

    def serve(self):
        while True:
            (ready, _, _) = select.select([self.input] + [i.input for i in self.build_pipes.values()], [] , [], 1)
            if self.input in ready:
                try:
                    r = self.input.read()
                    if len(r) == 0:
                        # EOF on pipe, server must have terminated
                        quit()
                    self.queue.extend(r)
                except (OSError, IOError):
                    pass
            if len(self.queue):
                    print("len(r)= %s" % (len(r)))
                    # simulate data parsing with sleep
                    time.sleep(0.1)

worker = TestWorker(os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', buffering=100_000))
worker.serve()
```

Output with time.sleep(0.1) in the server:

```
$ ./client-test.py 
len(r)= 65536
len(r)= 622592
len(r)= 65536
len(r)= 65536
len(r)= 626688
len(r)= 65536
len(r)= 65536
len(r)= 774144
...
```

Output without time.sleep(0.1) in the server:

```
$ ./client-test.py 
len(r)= 65536
len(r)= 774144
len(r)= 622592
len(r)= 860160
len(r)= 786432
len(r)= 626688
len(r)= 774144
len(r)= 786432
len(r)= 786432
len(r)= 774144
len(r)= 561152
...
```

Is there a way to increase the size of the chunks being transferred to make this communication more efficient? Why does adding `time.sleep(0.1)` reduce the size of the chunks?

Comment: *... the fact that those chunks are most of the time only 65536 bytes in size, and thus the parsing is done thousands of times.*. What is the relation between the size of a chunk and the fact that you parse thousands of time? Normally, you should have an indicator that the data is complete and ready to be parsed (either send the size before the data, or use an end of data indicator). So whether the whole data is received in one or numerous chunks should not matter and it should only be parsed once.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I agree this would be one way to solve it. Right now the code is doing naive parsing and searching for the end tag of the pickle structure, hence the inefficiency. I am still curious whether the size of the chunks can be changed programmatically (also in order to have a better understanding of this IPC).

Comment: A pipe uses a stream oriented protocol. It means that the only guarantee is that the reader will receive all the bytes in the correct order. There is no notion of *high level block* and you must add an additional protocol (size or end of data marker) if you need a full block for later processing. Alternatively, in you only send one single block, you can use the closing of the write side of the pipe as an end of data indicator.

Comment: @SergeBallesta what is the effect of the buffer size specified by open? "buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy. Pass [...] an integer > 1 to indicate the size in bytes of a fixed-size chunk buffer. Note that specifying a buffer size this way applies for binary buffered I/O"  (from https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open )